# Share buttons for chat events!

Tags: feature-request, chat, sharing, chat-event

[TildalWave recently had a great idea](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/9682/conversation/tildals-request): Add share buttons to chat events!

Here's a concept drawing of what I'd like it to be: Let's get rid of the export and delete links right after each title, and replace it with a chat-style popup-popper-upper:

[image]

Which would popup a popup!

[image]

Clicking share would bring up options to share the event to Twitter, Facebook, etc. Of course, the concept art is pretty crude (and devoid of red freehand circles), but it should be enough to give you an idea. I'm open to any way to get a share button, this was just the best one to pop into my mind.

Opinions?